# Different gearman server packages

Tags: server, package-management

What is the difference between the [`gearman-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gearman-server) package and the [`gearman-job-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gearman-job-server) package? Does one depend on the other?

Comment: I genuinely thought you asked about different german server packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `apt-cache show packagename` to see more about packages. You can read your answer in there:

```
$ apt-cache show gearman-server
[...]
Depends: perl, libgearman-client-perl, libdanga-socket-perl
[...]
Description-en: [...]
 This package contains both the Gearman server as well as the corresponding
 Perl bindings.

$ apt-cache show gearman-job-server
[...]
Depends: libboost-program-options1.46.1 [...]
[...]
Description-en: [...]
 This package contains the C reimplementation of the job server daemon
Homepage: http://launchpad.net/gearmand
```

So, basically, `gearman-job-server` (C/C++) is an alternative to `gearman-server` (Perl?), providing not all the exact same features.

Answer (score 0):

The [official gearman documentation](http://gearman.org/getting-started/) suggests `gearman-job-server`:

> Debain/Ubuntu Package
>   If you are running Debian/sid, run apt-get install `gearman-job-server`. This package may be slightly out of date due to the time it takes to propagate to the repositories.